# Why doesn't choose.files() open in the current working directory?

Tags: r, filechooser

When I change the working directory (e.g., from dir1 to dir2) then try to use `choose.files()`, the first time `choose.files()` runs it goes to dir1. If I cancel and run `choose.files()` a second time, then it opens in dir2. How can I get `choose.files()` to open in the most current working directory?

> I was encountering a different issue with `file.choose()` so I'm not
> able to use that function as a replacement

Here's an example:

```
getwd()                # say this is dir1
setwd(choose.dir())    # here I change the wd to dir2
getwd()                # currently set to dir2
choose.files()         # this opens in dir1
choose.files()         # this time it opens in dir2
```

I'd like to be able to use this progression to select a file from the current working directory. Appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: For anybody on linux/mac note that `choose.files()` is a Windows only function.

Comment: Description of `choose.files` in documentation : Use a Windows file dialog to choose a list of zero or more files interactively.  So @Dason is right. It's only for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this mask to the `default` argument:

```
choose.files(default=paste0(getwd(), "/*.*"))
```

From the help for `?choose.files`:

> If you would like to display files in a particular directory, give a
>   fully qualified file mask (e.g., "c:\*.*") in the default argument.

Comment: It returns `No documentation for ‘choose.files’` when I type `?choose.files`. I'm using Ubuntu. `choose.files` works only on windows.

Comment: What OS are you using Narendra?

Comment: @ I'm using Ubuntu.I just checked the documentation online. It says `choose.files` works only on Windows.